# How to simulate click in a href with class and rel defined?

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog

I tried every kind of examples that I looked here before I made this question. Só after hours trying solutions, I quit. May be someone with more javascript, html knowledge could help me. I really hope so.

That is my code:

```
<table class="tab_login">
<tr>
<td class="azul_escuro" align="right">You need to accept this document to proceed</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right"><a href="termos_uso.php" class="modal" rel="modal"><img      src="images/btn_enter.jpg" border="none" /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Pure and simple. Without form tag and all. But my client don´t want this. She decided that the modal window have to appear directly without click on the link. I don´t know what to do because when I simulate a click it seems to desconsider the class="modal" and rel="modal" related.

I´m using jquery-1.2.6.pack.js and jquery-modal-1.0.js

and in css:

```
/* MODAL */
.load { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 88px; height: 78px; margin: -39px 0 0 -44px; z-index: 99999;}
.bg_modal { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 99998; }
 .view_modal { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; text-align: left; z-index: 99998;         }
/*modal { visibility: hidden; cursor:pointer; }*/
.box_modal{width:429px; height:auto;}
```

What I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to open a pop-up windows without a click of the user. This behavior have been remove to kill pop-up adds.

So window.open() only work when an real mouse click event.

When you try to do it, modern browser will show a warning that the web site try to open a new window.

You could probably use an div overlay instead.

Comment: I just want a modal window appears. I tried a code to simulate the click event and it worked because opened the page but not worked as a modal with the mask and all. I think that is a problem to reference the "class". Well...